# Show translated content in view listing page when accessing translated site

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I have a view that filters for a specific content type (accommodation) and shows a paginated list for the user.

The site has a second language (Welsh) and a few of the content nodes have Welsh translations.

In theory, I should be able to visit the accommodation view, and if I was on the Welsh site (http://www.example.com/welsh/accommodation) I should see the Welsh nodes listed.

Sadly, this is not the case exactly.

My view is able to filter the Welsh translated nodes, but the view is spitting out the English text (title, URL, description etc) and not the Welsh versions.

This makes it pretty pointless, especially the fact that the URLs are rendered as the 'normal' English URLs and do not point to the Welsh site.

I've tried a tons of various view options but cannot fathom how to render the translated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was Panelizer causing issues. The site was using v3.0-beta, and Panelizer is currently on v4.0.

I also found a ticket about Panelizer not supporting translations in older versions.

For now, I have removed Panelizer and I am now able to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a filter to the view for the translation language?

You should be able to set one to only show content in the language of the current page (Which should be welsh if your language detection is setup and working correctly)

Comment: I do have a filter for language added - 'Content: Translation language (= Content language selected for page)'. Tried various seetings, still only seeing the English versions of the Welsh entries that should be showing.

Comment: I'm sure my language detection is working, as I can visit /welsh and get the interface in welsh, just not the view listings :/

Comment: That should be all you need. Do your accommodation nodes definitely have languages set and aren't language neutral?

Comment: They definitely have translations (maybe half do to actually, not 100% of them). If I visit the Welsh view, I get the right number of items listed (the nes that are translated) but it shows the English title, URL etc.

Comment: Do I have to have separate displays for the two languages?

Comment: What would you do differently in the 2 displays as you can only apply the filter like you already have. You could try changing the filter to specifically only show welsh. If that doesn't work and only show welsh translated items then im not sure what's gone wrong

Comment: Even changing the language filter to welsh, the correct nodes are shown, but the actual fields brought through are not the translated fields :(

Comment: What sort of translation have you got? Have you setup individual fields to be translatable? Or have you set the whole node to be translated? The whole node translated is the way to do it rather than individual fields

Comment: The whole node is set to be translated. We have investigated, and whilst it looks like the View is doing the correct query and getting the correct node IDs based on language, the next query along is clearly fetching the default language node, English. Currently trying to locate this query.